# Google Bii intents

Tags: android, app-actions

So I have a added Open App feature bii intents in this test application. But this is not working neither the open app is working in this.
While testing with the google voice plugin it is working as expected.
Is there something which I am missing or does these things take time to reflect in our application.
Thanks alot for your support.

I have testing the application using the android google voice plugin based on the testing doc provided by google. And it is working as expected.

Comment: I'm facing the same issues. For me only opening is working. When I deploy the app to my physical device it's not working. When I deploy to Android Automotive OS emulator it's working.